# Merging two tables with one table having an extra attribute

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables A and B that are identical. B has one extra attribute that holds boolean values.  I want to insert non identical values from A into B and set the boolean attributes of all newly added A values in B to false.  Here is my current work

Table A(id, first, last)
Table B(id, first, last, present*) 
*present is the boolean value

INSERT INTO B
 (SELECT * FROM A
    WHERE not exists(
        SELECT * FROM B
            WHERE id=A.id AND 
            first=A.first AND 
            last=A.last)
 )

This adds the values into B but leaves present as blank/null.  How do I go about assigning false to all newly added values into B.

Answer (score 0):

I was close!

INSERT INTO B (SELECT *,false FROM A WHERE not exists( SELECT * FROM B WHERE id=A.id AND first=A.first AND last=A.last) )

I needed to add " ,false " following the SELECT * in the beginning of the SELECT statement